# Special validation of email field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple settings section in my app where people can change various account settings including email. Once they have posted the form, I'm using `FormRequest` to validate all the fields agains some rules, easy. But how do I validate email field? here is what I mean. In case user wanna update the email, we need to make sure it hasn't been taken by someone else. But we can't define rules as

```
'email' => 'email|unique:users',
```

because, if they don't want to update the email, they would never be able to submit the form (by default, when page loads, I display current email prefilled in the field). So, we need this email to be unique to the table except for the current user's email. how to correctly validate the email field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple you have ti just define that which user email address is ignore,Yes you can ignore multiple email address in validation.

For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address. You only want to throw a validation error if the user provides an e-mail address that is already used by a different user. To tell the unique rule to ignore the user's ID, you may pass the ID as the third parameter:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,current_user_id'
```

[Form more detailed information click here.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 0):

you are close, you just have to add in more variable to your rules as the following:

`'unique:users,email,'.Auth::id().',id'`

the statement above will build unique rules and ignore the email which own by the current authenticated user

Comment: the code above is just served as the brief solution, you are always advised to create your own customize validation class and methods then register them via a service provider.

Comment: 's suggestion is also on the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique